# How to insert record into SQL Server using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to insert a row in a table, but it's just updating the table. How to insert a new row in the table using Entity Framework?

```
public partial class Transformer_GSM
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double KW { get; set; }
}
```

Table columns

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
[KW] [float] NOT NULL
```

Table name: `Transformer_GSM`

In the context  -

```
 public DbSet<Transformer_GSM> Transformer_GSM { get; set; }
```

Code:

```
public IHttpActionResult GSM(double KW)
{
        try
        {
            using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
            {
                DATA.Transformer_GSM  t = new Transformer_GSM();
                t.KW = KW;
                DB.Transformer_GSM.Add(t);
                DB.SaveChanges();
            }

            var response = new
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "Transformer data saved",
            };

            return Ok(response);
}
```

Comment: Should work. But you could use `DB.Transformer_GSM.Create()` instead of new operator.

Comment: not working i think name is same . in context and db.table name.class file and context set name. it should be plural.entity set name and name  both are Transformer_GSM

Comment: Update your question and show us the `Transformer_GSM` class

Comment: @ZorgoZ `Create` will create instance EF will know nothing about.

Comment: I agree on the plural but do not think that is the problem. How does hour construcrot of DATA.Transformer_GSM look like?

Comment: updated class in question. @JohnyL

Comment: I see that it's `partial`. What is the rest of the class?

Comment: @JohnyL, actually EF will also populate references with `create` - but not with `new`. Anyway, you still have to add it tobthe collection.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that since the PK is an identity column you need to tell EF that, otherwise it thinks you are updating the record with ID = 0.

```
public partial class Transformer_GSM
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public double KW { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, `int` primary keys are IDENTITY for EF by default.